# How to use Bootstrap 5 JS in an Angular 11 component TS

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a project that uses Angular 11, we want to use Bootstrap 5 native JS, without third parties like ng-bootstrap, MDB, or ngx-bootstrap (We are not using jQuery as well). I know using JS libraries on TS is not ideal.

**The problem is how to import Bootstrap JS and use its objects and methods in Angular's TS components.**

Initially I thought installing the following packages would be enough:

```
npm i bootstrap@next
npm i @types/bootstrap
```

Both have been imported in the `package.json` and are available in `node_modules`. I've also imported `"scripts": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ]` inside of `angular.json`, but I still cannot use them.

For example, if I do:

```
import { Carousel } from 'bootstrap';
...
carousel: Carousel | any;
...
this.carousel = document.getElementById('video-carousel')
this.carousel.interval = false;
```

Where `'bootstrap'` is [`'@types/Bootstrap'`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap). The carousel shouldn't cycle automatically, but it does. This happens with every other Bootstrap type.

Comment: You could pretend it's a regular old HTML + JS page, and include the <link> and <script>, then simply use the classes.

Comment: @ChrisG check this example, it's the same as yours but with a collapse, which doesn't work. I've actually been having a similar issue a project of my own that's got a similar stack as OP's. https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-http-qoffm?file=/src/app/app.component.html I'm trying to solve the same problem, because the only thing that's "fixed" it so far was to use ng-bootstrap, and that's not really what I want. If you have any ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: @ChrisG I'd prefer to avoid using inline scripts inside the HTML, and do it directly from the component's TS.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are using the carousel element in a bit wrong way. In order to use the carousel methods you should initialize a `Carousel` element with the appropriate config.

Instead selecting the native HTML element that represents the carousel you should create `new Carousel(elementRef, config)` and make any further changes by referring the class.

```html
<div #carouselExampleSlidesOnly class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item red active">
      Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item orange">
      Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item blue">
      Text 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
...
 @ViewChild("carouselExampleSlidesOnly") carouselElement: ElementRef<
    HTMLElement
  >;
  carouselRef: Carousel;
...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.carouselRef = new Carousel(this.carouselElement.nativeElement, {
      slide: false
    });
  }
...
```

This will create a carousel element that doesn't auto slide.

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-carousel-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example, where you can pause and play the carousel, keep in mind that beside importing the `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` in the `scripts` inside your `angular.json` you should also import `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"` in the `styles`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official bootstrap documentation, Carousel requires bootstrap's own Javascript plugins and [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org). In order for your carousel to work, be sure to include `popper.min.js` before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` / `bootstrap.bundle.j`s which contains Popper and that should do the trick. I was having the same issue with the bootstrap dropdown-toggle. It didn't work. Instead of importing `"scripts": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ]` in `angular.json`. I imported
`"scripts": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ]` (which includes popper) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you will add `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` in your `angular.json`, your component might not understand that. Batter to add only what
is required in your component to support tree shaking.

In your component where you want to use `bootstrap` functionality ( like modal ), import the specified bootstrap js file like below

```
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

Define a variable for bootstrap `modal` and `@ViewChild` like below

```
modalDirect: Bootstrap.Modal;
@ViewChild('demoModal') input;
Now create a method to open the bootstrap5 modal on click of a button
open(element): void {
  this.modalDirect = new Bootstrap.Modal(element, {});
}
```

now it should work

here you can get an example

https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/bootstrap5-angular10-without-jQuery/blob/master/src/app/components/home/home.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and then I realized I had imported the scripts (and styles) in the wrong place. Be sure that you're importing inside

```
"architect": { 
  "build": {
    "options": {
       ...
     "styles": [],
     "scripts": []
     }
  }
}
```

I was actually importing mine inside "test": { .... }.